# MySQL query that performs LEFT JOIN but includes parent record's ID?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table of `articles` with some articles having children (but only 1 level of children).

I want to have a view that shows articles grouped by their parent ID. This is what I have so far.

```
select 
    `articles`.`id` AS `group_id`, `child`.`id` AS `article_id`,  `articles`.`created` AS `date`
from
    `articles`
    left join `articles` as `child` on (`articles`.`id` = `child`.`parent_id`)
where
    `child`.`id` is not null;
```

And above produces these results.

```
trend_id,article_id,date
3374,3172,"2015-04-30 18:31:12"
3374,3211,"2015-04-30 18:31:12"
3374,3213,"2015-04-30 18:31:12"
3297,3217,"2015-04-30 18:31:10"
3170,3222,"2015-04-30 18:31:08"
3187,3226,"2015-04-30 18:31:09"
3187,3281,"2015-04-30 18:31:09"
3170,3284,"2015-04-30 18:31:08"
3170,3285,"2015-04-30 18:31:08"
3170,3320,"2015-04-30 18:31:08"
3187,3323,"2015-04-30 18:31:09"
3187,3333,"2015-04-30 18:31:09"
3187,3355,"2015-04-30 18:31:09"
3297,3393,"2015-04-30 18:31:10"
```

The `article_id` column does not contain the parent ID, but only the children (which is expected with this kind of join).

What I need is something like this.

```
trend_id,article_id,date
3374,3374,"2015-04-30 18:31:12"  <-- trend_id is repeated as article_id
3374,3172,"2015-04-30 18:31:12"
3374,3211,"2015-04-30 18:31:12"
3374,3213,"2015-04-30 18:31:12"
3297,3297,"2015-04-30 18:31:10"  <-- trend_id is repeated as article_id
3297,3217,"2015-04-30 18:31:10"
3170,3170,"2015-04-30 18:31:08"  <-- trend_id is repeated as article_id
3170,3222,"2015-04-30 18:31:08"
```

I've been trying to modify the query to get the above results, but have had no success. I suspect it requires 2 joins but I'm having no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu could solve this with a UNION:

```
select 
    `articles`.`id` AS `group_id`, `child`.`id` AS `article_id`,  `articles`.`created` AS `date`
from
    `articles`
    left join `articles` as `child` on (`articles`.`id` = `child`.`parent_id`)
where
    `child`.`id` is not null;
UNION 
select distinct
    `articles`.`id` AS `group_id`, `articles`.`id` AS `article_id`,  `articles`.`created` AS `date`
from
    `articles`
```

Or something along those lines

Answer (score 2):

In such cases it might help to keep it simple at first and break your desired result set down into its component parts.
You already have the *child* entries, now all you need is the *parent* rows.

So one approach would be to simply `UNION` the *parent* rows with your existing query:

```
SELECT 
    `articles`.`id` AS `group_id`, 
    `child`.`id` AS `article_id`,  
    `articles`.`created` AS `date`
FROM
    `articles`
    LEFT JOIN `articles` AS `child` ON (`articles`.`id` = `child`.`parent_id`)
WHERE
    `child`.`id` IS NOT NULL 

UNION ALL
SELECT 
    `articles`.`id` AS `group_id`, 
    `articles`.`id` AS `article_id`,  
    `articles`.`created` AS `date`
FROM
    `articles`
WHERE
    `articles`.`id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `parent_id` FROM `articles`);
```